# Google plus API Issues

Tags: google-plus

Working with Google Plus API, I have enabled the google+ api in developer console and regenrated the appkey multiple times and trying to access the profile using profile.get but everytime i am getting the following issue:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

Here is the link, i am trying to do:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/113377691202864347297?key={myKey}

passing my generated key for that domain, i am getting the above error. why it is not working

Screenshot of Enabled API's

[image: API]

Comment: Did you **read** the error message? You haven't activated the API for your project

Comment: i did activated that, i can show screenshot here

Comment: any idea what is going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you're using the wrong API key. The API key is not a client ID or a client secret - it shouldn't have '.' in it. In the new console (https://developers.google.com/console) they are generated under the Credentials > Public API Access section and should look something like 'AIzaSyC-iPgOiU2hSqnpjc-KrtHpwThsWh_hQdO'.

If you've made one make sure that the allowable IP addresses or browser URLs (depending on key type) include the one you're making the call from. I included a screenshot of the key section below.

[image: A screenshot of the key section]

Comment: Thanks, that helped solve the issue.. Also do you have any idea how to get email address and phone number from the google+, i managed to get all other stuff but above two are missing, but the same i can see in the profile section

Comment: Email isn't public, so you'll have to have the user grant you access via OAuth 2.0. You can use the "email" and "profile" scopes. In that case you'll make the call with an access token rather than a key. Because the user has to grant access, its a bit more complicated. There are lots of ways to implement, but take a look at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button-javascript for one.

Comment: i will make another call too, but guide me how

Answer (score -2):

Which jar should i include for retrieving public posts of user.
Iam using google+ v1 api jars but there seems to be some problem with json. It is not able to resolve it.

Comment: you should comment below the answer or the question.

Comment: Hi @user3737608, you can't use the reply feature to ask another question. Either open a new question or add a comment asking for clarification. Check the guidelines for how to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer